# R: first N of all permutations

Tags: r

I'm looking for a function that

- can list all n! permutations of a given input vector (typically just the sequence `1:n`)
- can also list just the first N of all n! permutations

The first requirement is met, e.g., by `permn()` from package `combinat`, `permutations()` from package `e1071`, or `permutations()` from package `gtools`. However, I'm positive that there is yet another function from some package that also provides the second feature. I used it once, but have since forgotten its name.

Edit:
The definition of "first N" is arbitrary: the function just needs an internal enumeration scheme which is always followed, and should break after N permutations are computed.

As Spacedman correctly pointed out, it's crucial that the function does not compute more permutations than actually needed (to save time).

Edit - solution: I remembered what I was using, it was `numperm()` from package `sna`. `numperm(4, 7)` gives the 7th permutation of elements `1:4`, for the first N, one has to loop.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not permutations(n)[1:N, ]?

Comment: permutations(100,5)[1:10,] will take some times... I imagine thats the problem.

Comment: You should probably have some sort of definition of what you mean by 'first'.

Comment: @Spacedman exactly, @John edited my question to explain what I mean by "first".

Comment: Perhaps you can code up Narayana Pandita's algorithm in R. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Systematic_generation_of_all_permutations. Sort first and then apply algorithm. Comment instead of answer because i don't know R. Feel free to post an answer with this if you think it is suitable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the best way to approach this would be to construct an *iterator* that could produce the list of permutations rather than using a function like `permn` which generates the entire list up front (an expensive operation).

An excellent place to look for guidance on constructing such objects is the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module in the Python standard library.  Itertools has been partially re-implemented for R as [a package of the same name](http://crantastic.org/packages/itertools).

The following is an example that uses R's itertools to implement a port of the Python generator that creates iterators for permutations:

```
require(itertools)

permutations <- function(iterable) {
  # Returns permutations of iterable. Based on code given in the documentation
  # of the `permutation` function in the Python itertools module:
  #   http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations
  n <- length(iterable)
  indicies <- seq(n)
  cycles <- rev(indicies)
  stop_iteration <- FALSE

  nextEl <- function(){
    if (stop_iteration){ stop('StopIteration', call. = FALSE) }
    if (cycles[1] == 1){ stop_iteration <<- TRUE } # Triggered on last iteration

    for (i in rev(seq(n))) {
      cycles[i] <<- cycles[i] - 1
      if ( cycles[i] == 0 ){
        if (i < n){
          indicies[i:n] <<- c(indicies[(i+1):n], indicies[i])
        }
        cycles[i] <<- n - i + 1
      }else{
        j <- cycles[i]
        indicies[c(i, n-j+1)] <<- c(indicies[n-j+1], indicies[i])
        return( iterable[indicies] )
      }
    }
  }

  # chain is used to return a copy of the original sequence 
  # before returning permutations. 
  return( chain(list(iterable), new_iterator(nextElem = nextEl)) )

}
```

> **To misquote [Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only tried it, not proved it correct."**

For the first 3 permutations of the sequence `1:10`, `permn` pays a heavy price for computing unnecessary permutations:

```
> system.time( first_three <- permn(1:10)[1:3] )
   user  system elapsed 
134.809   0.439 135.251 
> first_three
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10  9

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 10  8  9)
```

However, the iterator returned by `permutations` can be queried for only the first three elements which spares a lot of computations:

```
> system.time( first_three <- as.list(ilimit(permutations(1:10), 3)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002 
> first_three
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10  9

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9  8 10
```

The Python algorithm does generate permutations in a different order than `permn`.

Computing all the permutations is still possible:

```
> system.time( all_perms <- as.list(permutations(1:10)) )
   user  system elapsed 
498.601   0.672 499.284
```

Though much more expensive as the Python algorithm makes heavy use of loops compared to `permn`. Python actually implements this algorithm in C which compensates for the inefficiency of interpreted loops.

The code is available [in a gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/832723).  If anyone has a better idea, fork away!

Comment: there is now an [iterpc package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterpc/index.html), implemented with Rcpp, which does exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

In my version of `R`/`combinat`, the function `permn()` is just over thirty lines long. One way would be to make a copy of `permn` and change it to stop early.

Comment: That is a last resort. However, it makes communicating certain solutions more complicated when I have to include helper functions as well. Being able to just reference a CRAN-package for that task is less wordy and error-prone.

Comment: For sure, if you can find an existing implementation, that's clearly the way to go (I had a quick look, and couldn't find one.) The real point of my answer was that in the absence of an existing implementation creating one that does exactly what you want is not that hard.