# Compute N random permutations of a vector of 36 elements

Tags: r, permutation

I have a vector V containing 36 elements, 18 are "0" and 18 are "1".
I would like to compute N random (not the first N) permutation of this vector.

I could do as follow:

```
library(combinat)
N <- 100 # or 200, 300, 500... max 1000
V <- c(rep(0, 18), rep(1, 18))
n <- factorial(36) # total number of unique possible permutations
p <- unique(permn(V))[sample(1:n, N)]
```

But I quickly run into the combinatorial explosion problem, as
`sample(1:n, N)` returns `Error in 1:n : result would be too long a vector`

and

`permn(V)` returns `Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) : vector size specified is too large`

Is there another (better) way to do this?

Comment: If you want to do `N` random combinations of `0` and `1` why are you sampling from `1:n`?

Comment: do the permutations have to be unique? or could you just do `replicate(N, sample(V))`?

Comment: Yes, the permutations have to be unique

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: first N of all permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031613/r-first-n-of-all-permutations)

Comment: There is no `factorial(36)` possible permutations because you are dealing with permutations of multisets (all 0 are same as well all 1) - see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets). You can use `multicool` package and its function `allPerm`. However, there are still `485200708` parmutations and it takes some time to generate them all.

Comment: @JakubBuček There are `factorial(36)` total permutations

`p1 =  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

`p2 = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0` and so on, all of them have 36 elements, 18 are "0" and 18 are '1"

Comment: Take a look into your sampling function. It's not sampling 0 and 1, but from 1 to n

Comment: @pisistrato Please check the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets). You can not distinct one 0 from another 0 so you count some permutations more times.

Comment: @PoGibas the `[sample(1:n, N)]` is just to extract N random numbers between 1 and n, where n is the total number of unique permutations, which I would compute with `unique(permn(V))`
@JakubBuček sorry, you are right, some of the permutation will be exactly the same, for instance when just the 0 are permuted and kept as the first 18 elements. Apologies again

Comment: @JakubBuček, your logic and links are spot on. Just curious, how did you obtain the number of permutations (I.e. 485200708)?

Comment: @JosephWood Yeah, I have noticed the difference in your and my number. I used `multicool` package with following code: `x <- rep(0:1, each=18); multinom(x)`. That gave me `485200708` permutations. Now, I have noticed parameter `useDouble` in `multinom` function that prevents integer overflow. So `multinom(x, useDouble=TRUE)` gives the correct number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, there are not `factorial(36)` results as you have repeated elements. If we did, to get the total number, we can use the `gmp` package to get:

```
gmp::factorialZ(36)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 371993326789901217467999448150835200000000
```

What we are actually dealing with are called permutations of **[multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)** (as @JakubBucek points out in the comments). Using either the package `RcppAlgos` (which I authored) or the package `arrangements`, we can easily and correctly calculate the total number of results, and more importantly generate the desired results.

First off, the actual number of results:

```
arrangements::npermutations(0:1, freq = c(18, 18), bigz = TRUE)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 9075135300

RcppAlgos::permuteCount(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18))
[1] 9075135300
```

This comes as a consequence of combinatorics. That is, we must divide by the product of the number of permutations of like elements:

```
gmp::factorialZ(36) / gmp::pow.bigz(gmp::factorialZ(18), 2)
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 9075135300
```

Now, to generate your random permutations. For package `arrangements` we use the `nsample` argument. Additionally we can set the seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(123)
r1 <- arrangements::permutations(0:1, freq = c(18, 18), nsample = 10)

set.seed(123)
r2 <- arrangements::permutations(0:1, freq = c(18, 18), nsample = 10)

dim(r1)
[1] 10 36

identical(r1, r2)
[1] TRUE

## only showing 10 columns
head(r1[,1:10])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     1
[2,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     0
[4,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    0     0
[5,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     1
[6,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
```

And for `RcppAlgos`, we call `permuteSample` using the analogous arguments `n` and `seed`:

```
r3 <- RcppAlgos::permuteSample(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18), n = 10, seed = 42)
r4 <- RcppAlgos::permuteSample(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18), n = 10, seed = 42)

identical(r3, r4)
[1] TRUE

dim(r3)
[1] 10 36
```

Both packages are very efficient as well. It takes less than a second to generate 1000 random permutations:

```
system.time(RcppAlgos::permuteSample(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18), n = 1000))
 user  system elapsed 
0.051   0.000   0.052 

system.time(arrangements::permutations(0:1, freq = c(18, 18), nsample = 1000))
 user  system elapsed 
0.249   0.000   0.249
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `RcppAlgos::permuteSample` samples the possible permutations *without replacement*, while `arrangements::permutations` samples the permutations *with replacement*.

Comment: @jblood94, I know your claim is true for my package. How did you verify for `arrangements`? I went through the source code and found the `C` function `draw_multiset_permutations`, however I could not easily decipher how the sampling was performed.

Comment: Also worth noting that in either package, one could generate any sample of integers (with or without replacement) and pass it to `sampleVec` for `RcppAlgos` and `index` for `arrangements` in order to avoid assumptions.

Comment: Not by stepping through the code, but try `set.seed(1359965434); arrangements::permutations(1:3, freq = c(1,1,1), nsample = 2)`. So, obviously with replacement. It also appears to be sampling uniformly. Try `x <- tabulate(colSums(t(arrangements::permutations(0:1, freq = c(3,3), nsample = 1e6))*2^(0:5))); x[x != 0]`.

Answer (score 2):

@Joseph Wood got the perfect answer. Just in case you need a list of those sampled permutations use:

```
r <- RcppAlgos::permuteSample(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18), n = 100)
r <- lapply(1:dim(r)[1], function(x) {r[x,]})
```

Comment: Nice addition. Also note that the package `arrangements` has an argument called `type` (I think) that allows you to return a list, so it’s a little cleaner.

Comment: The `type` argument has been renamed as `layout` for clearness.

Answer (score 1):

For quickly generating many permutations, the `Rfast` package has `colShuffle` that will permute each column of a matrix. (It also has `rowShuffle` for row-wise permutations, but that function currently works properly only for square matrices.)

For 10 samples of the OP's vector:

```
n <- 10 # number of samples
colShuffle(matrix(rep(0:1, 18), 36, n))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1     0
#>  [2,]    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     0
#>  [3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [5,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     1
#>  [6,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [7,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     0
#>  [9,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1     0
#> [10,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
#> [11,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1     1
#> [12,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
#> [13,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1     1
#> [14,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1     1
#> [15,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     1
#> [16,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
#> [17,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
#> [18,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0     1
#> [19,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0     0
#> [20,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
#> [21,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
#> [22,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0     1
#> [23,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
#> [24,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
#> [25,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0     0
#> [26,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     1
#> [27,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
#> [28,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    0     1
#> [29,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
#> [30,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0     1
#> [31,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     0
#> [32,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    1    0     1
#> [33,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1     0
#> [34,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     0
#> [35,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
#> [36,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     0
```

Benchmarking:

```
n <- 1e3

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  RfastCol = colShuffle(matrix(rep(0:1, 18), 36, n)),
  RcppAlgos = permuteSample(0:1, freqs = c(18, 18), n = n),
  arrangements = permutations(0:1, freq = c(18, 18), nsample = n)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>      RfastCol   577.8   708.30   852.679   753.80   800.30   9889.8   100
#>     RcppAlgos 15150.7 15297.70 15484.137 15383.30 15590.70  17604.2   100
#>  arrangements 89671.4 90162.85 91229.152 90733.90 91576.95 102990.4   100
```

NB1: `RcppAlgos::permuteSample` samples the permutations *without replacement*.

NB2: `Rfast::colShuffle` does not respect the global RNG (see comments).

Comment: This is nice. I will say, I don’t think `colShuffle` respects the global RNG. If you try a small example with a given seed via `set.seed` and try it again, you get different results. Maybe I’m doing something wrong, but I don’t see any mention in the docs.

Comment: Interesting. The function does seem to [set its own seed](https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/blob/00f3d0f46ccddf99e3418bb271f7216de7726041/inst/include/Rfast/matrix.hpp#L1518).